# How to Apply a Getter/Setter to an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, getter-setter

How would I apply a getter/setter to an object itself when defining it?

For example, I want to make

`myobj = 123` run `console.log(123)`

I know that it is possible by using `class extends`, but I want to find a simpler way that defines the getter/setter, *possibly* in the constructor.

Does anyone know how? Is this even possible?

If you need any more information, or if I wasn't clear enough, let me know. `- JacobTDC`

Comment: There's no object in `myobj = 123`

Comment: @MinusFour, that was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getters` and `setters` are relevant for object's properties, not for variable assigning, like in your question.

The `class extends` is not really relevant here.

Check this for example[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```js
var language = {
  set current(name) {
    this.log.push(name);
  },
  log: []
}

language.current = 'EN';
console.log(language.log); // ['EN']

language.current = 'FA';
console.log(language.log); // ['EN', 'FA']
```

[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) code taken from MDN

Comment: Yes, I realize that this is possible, I just don't want to do it like that.

Comment: I'm afraid variable assignment is not something you can "getter" in javascript (And i'm not even sure which language support this).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually well described at MDN [Working with Objects, Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) - this article provides a simple example of getters and setters usage in JavaScript.

A modified (to fit your problem) version of this example would look like this:

```
var o = {
    set myvar(value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.myvar = value;
    }
};

o.myvar = 123;
// Should call console.log(123)
```

---

There's also another way to do this - you could use ES2015 Proxies and their [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) and [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) traps. This could be useful in situations where for some reason you don't want to modify the original object.

These two proxies are "global" per object (as in - they catch gets/sets performed on ALL properties of the proxied object). Here's a simple example based on the linked article:

```
var o = new Proxy({}, {
    set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
        target[prop] = value;

        // "set" proxy is global, so it will catch calling assignment operator on ALL properties of this object
        if (prop === "myvar") {
            console.log(value)
        }

        return true
    }
});

o.myvar = 123;
// Should call console.log(123)
```

Comment: Could you point me to where in the page that is described, because I have been looking over that exact page for the past 30 minutes, and it's all starting to look the same.

Comment: The first link I've provided points directly to the said example (the one with getter defined on ``b`` property).

Comment: I've edited my answer with two examples, maybe this will help a bit.

Comment: Thanks, @mdziekon!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.defineProperty()` to define a setter for the property:

```
var a = {}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'myobj', {
  set: function (value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
})
a.myobj = 111
```